# MIndsDB successfully starts but throws socket error on connection

Tags: mysql, mindsdb

I am trying to connect to the MindsDB mysql api using the bellow command:

```bash
mysql -h localhost -u mindsdb -p
```

but I got an error:

```bash
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

The mindsdb server is successfully started and I can see in the logs that both HTTP and MySQL API are available.
Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: "an error". Are we meant to guess? Maybe the details of the error are related to why it doesn't connect.

Comment: Guess 1 - The user is `mindsdb` rather than `midnsdb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to connect to the MySQL API, you will need to always use the IP address (in your case 127.0.0.1). That is because for MySQL the localhost is not the same as 127.0.0.1. If 'localhost' is used then the client tries to connect to the UNIX socket, otherwise, it needs to use the TCP socket."